# Tipos de datos de componentes del form c#

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Hola queria saber que tipo de datos son los siguientes componentes que saque de la tool box visual studio 2012

> radTimePicker1
>
> checkBox
>
> roundedButtonGray1

queria para colocarlo tipo

```
public date radTimePicker 1 { get; set }
```

De ante mano, gracias

y como lo escribiria por ejemplo

```
this.obj.IsReleasedGroupedComms = this.TxtGroupingRelease.Text;
```

Lo tengo en la misma instancia, pero no se como escribir lo de arriba pero para el radTimePicker, me pueden guiar por favor

Son controles de telerik ya tengo el control en mi interfaz

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Solo quiero guardar la hora indicada de ese dataTimePicker1

El DataTimePicker1 lo puse cono un Date TIme en una clase 
`public DateTime dateTimePicker1 { get; set; }` 
Pero tampoco me deja acceder a el
 `this.obj.radTimePicker1 = this.radTimePicker1;`
 el error que muestra es :

> "Cannot implicitly convert type 'Telerik.WinControls.UI.RadTimePicker'
>   to 'int'

Comment: recomendación siempe buscar en la pagina oficial https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/checkbox-control-overview-windows-forms

Comment: son controles de telerik? porque querrias dimencionarlo dentro de una clase?

Comment: no entiendo eso de "colocarlo tipo" no se colocan tipo nada de eso que mencionas, los controles los debes poner en el diseñador del form y al darle un nombre en la propiedad lo accedes por medio de este

Comment: @gbianchi si son de telerik, tienes un ejemplo de como se debe hacer?
ya tengo el control en mi interfaz https://www.imtp.tk/im/zznz8.jpg
Solo quiero guardar la hora indicada de ese dataTimePicker1

Comment: no ni idea, pero deberias haberlo aclarado ;)

Comment: okay, ya esta editado.

Comment: y telerik no te dice que tipo de datos maneja? no es un DateTime?

Comment: De hecho lo puse cono un Date TIme en una clase  public DateTime dateTimePicker1 { get; set; }
Pero tampoco me deja acceder a el this.obj.radTimePicker1 = this.radTimePicker1;

el error que muestra es : "Cannot implicitly convert type 'Telerik.WinControls.UI.RadTimePicker' to 'int'

Comment: Pero no tenes que usar o dimensionar un objeto en tu clase. solo tenes que acceder al valor que guarda. Entendes el concepto de objetos visuales y sus datos?